# Referencing Firebug Console Inside of a Custom Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, object, console, firebug

I have several custom Javascript objects and want to do some debugging via the Firebug console inside of them. However, if I try to use console.log(), I get an error about console not being defined. I tried referencing console as window.console and it made no difference. When I run a check to see if console is defined, it returns false:

```
if(window.console && window.console.firebug)
```

So, my question is, how can I reference the Firebug console inside of my custom objects so that I can do my debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around a bit and trying different things, I believe the problem was being caused by the ColorZilla Firefox extension. I disabled it and re-started Firefox and my console statements now work.

Hopefully this will save others a lot of time and frustration!